# How to get date from static string?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, fscalendar

I want to get full date with time like my below code,

```
func findDate(date: Date)
{
        let format1: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        format1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let onlyDate = format1.string(from: date) // Here date is like 2019-11-21 

        let dateStr = "\(onlyDate) 10:00 AM"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar.current
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

        let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
        print(newDate) // It returns nil

        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let newDateStrInUTC = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate ?? Date()) // Not proper due to newDate = nil
}
```

In `findDate` function `date` argument has date like `2019-11-21 18:30:00 +0000`. I want to add my custom time (10:00 AM) in that date.

I received this date (`2019-11-21 18:30:00 +0000`) from `FSCalender`.

I want Output like this `2019-11-21 12:00 PM`

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465205/how-to-add-minutes-to-current-time-in-swift

Comment: Do You want Your output like this - 2019-11-21 18:30:00 PM

Comment: In Your findDate function - why are You passing +0000?

Comment: You haven't understood my question. My problem is not with +0000. @RipaSaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line in `findDate(date: Date)` function.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"
```

Replace it to following, and your function should start working as expected.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
```

**Explanation:**

**HH** is used for setting date to 24 Hours format.

Use small **hh**, if you wanted to show date in 12 Hours format with AM/PM

As you are appending `10:00 AM` to your `onlyDate` String. You should use `hh:mm a` for proper conversion from String to Date.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I was forget and just write `HH` instead of `hh`. Again thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It will change time components without changing date.

```
func findDate(date: Date)
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeString = "10:00 AM"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let customDate = formatter.date(from: timeString)
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: customDate!)
    let min = calendar.component(.minute, from: customDate!)
    let sec = calendar.component(.second, from: customDate!)
    let resultDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: min, second: sec, of: date)
    print(resultDate!)
}
```

Now you can use resultDate according to your requirement. Also take care of those optionals according to your need.

Comment: I have time string like "10:00 AM". If i want to set time component as per your answer then i have to separate hour & minute from time string and i have to set 24 hour time formate but i have AM, PM formate. For this i have to write some messy code. I want simple way to get full date with time. @Fahad Masood.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
let dateTimeToConvert = yourDateTimeHere
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_EN")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm a"
formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
let converted = formatter.date(from: "\(dateTimeToConvert)")
print(converted)
```

Note, the locale I have used is different, simply use yours. I have also used a date time to convert with this. But you can achieve what you want by simply adding the time in after date conversion.

You can also mess around with the date time structure like so

```
format = "HH:mm: a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
```

this format when used will like like this

"9:01 am on January 12, 2019"